# Cannot add java files to the paid Product Flavor

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have created a project with two flavours. The free flavour I can add java files but the paid on I cannot create java and res directory to add java files. I have manually created both the free and paid directory.

```
productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.sagar.joker.free"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId "com.sagar.joker.paid"
        }
    }
```

[image: Check the Project Structure]

Comment: You need to mark those as sourceSets within Gradle

Comment: @cricket_007  How do I add the sourceSets within Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose active flavor in Android Studio in BuildVariants in left bottom corner.

[image: choose flavor]

Comment: How do I add java files to the paid directory? please check the screenshot

Comment: First of all add new directory there (your package). Than change active BuildVariants. After this you will be able to add java files.

Comment: I am not able to add the MainActivity in the AndroidManifest do happen to what the problem could be ?

Comment: You should have 3 source folders: main, free and paid. Where is your activity placed?

Comment: My activity is placed in free and paid source folders

Comment: Yes I am using the main package name: com.sagar.joker

Comment: And what do you mean by not able to add activity? You mean autocomplete isn't working?

Comment: Okay it's done my bad I forgot to add package to the java file

Answer (score 4):

1. In the top of right windows, make sure has switched the structure to Project.
   [image]
2. Right click "res" folder, chooose follow **New>Folder>Java Folder**

[image]

3. choose the target productFlavor name :

[image]